# Questions About Base and Hausdorff in Topology

Tags: general-topology

I am really confused about below questions. I am new both in this platform and below topics. I hope, I was clearly explain the questions.

For ∀n∈$\mathbb{Z}$<sup>+</sup>

Based on $B_n$ = {n, n+1, n+2...}, **B** = {$B_n$|n ∈ $\mathbb{Z}$<sup>+</sup>} family of sets are given. According to this,

(i) Family **B** is the base for a topology on $\mathbb{Z}$<sup>+</sup>. Show it.
(ii) Show that there is no Hausdorff by writing the topology on $\mathbb{Z}$<sup>+</sup> produced by **B**.
(iii) Show that the sequence (2,4,6,8,...) in $\mathbb{Z}$<sup>+</sup> converges to each point according to topology produced by the family **B**

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

$(B_n), n \in \Bbb Z^+$ is a base for a topology, because their union is $\Bbb Z^+$ and the collection is closed under finite intersections.

The space is not Hausdorff, because there is no basic element that contains $1$, but does not contain $2$. So $1$ and $2$ cannot be separated by open sets. Writing out the whole topology is not needed (though not hard).

Let $n \in \Bbb Z$. If $B_k$ is any basic element that contains $n$, then $k \le n$ and then all members of the sequence that are $>n$ (all but finitely many one, thus) are in $B_k$. So the sequence converges to $n$.

Answer (score 0):

(i) to show that $\mathcal{B}=\{B_n\}$ is a base for some topology on some space $X$, one should shows that $$\forall A, B \in \mathcal{B}\quad\exists C_1,\ldots,C_n\in\mathcal{B}\quad A\cap B = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}C_n$$
and that $\bigcup_{B\in\mathcal{B}}\ B = X$

This conditions easily verified in your case $X=\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $B=\{\{n, n+1, n+2, \ldots\}| n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$.

The topology will be same as $\mathcal{B}$ because $\mathcal{B}$ is closed under union too. So all open sets will be the form $\{n, n+1, n+2, \ldots\}$.

(ii) For all open $U$ if $n \in U$ then $n + 1 \in U$ use this to show that point $n$ and $n+1$ don't satisfy Hausdorff condition.

(iii) Sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$ $\iff$ $\forall$ open $U$ s.t $x\in U$ $\exists N\ \forall n \ge N\ x_n \in U$

in out case $x_n = 2\cdot n$.
By the property that for all open $U$ if $n \in U$ then $n + 1 \in U$ if $x_n\in U$ then $\forall m\ge n\ x_m \in U$

So you only need to verify that
$\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}^+\ \forall$ open $U$ s.t $x\in U$ $\exists n$ such that $x_n \in U$. That you can derive from the form of open sets in our case.